# mongodb: maxTimeMS ignored

Tags: mongodb, timeout

After trying with different drivers and clients, we suffer with mongodb timeout on find query.

Even Profiling logs the settings and issue well.

```
       2014-08-13T23:46:43.218+0200 [conn80] query mdb.fcol query: { $query: { 
       unid: "39068119d2924babffedde92ef937bd0" }, $maxTimeMS: 100 } planSummary: 
       IXSCAN { unid: 1 } ntoskip:0 nscanned:1 nscannedObjects:1 keyUpdates:0 
       numYields:1 locks(micros) r:334 nreturned:1 reslen:341 2181ms
```

Though `$maxTimeMS: 100`, the query takes 2181ms.

How to force mongodb to respect the timeout and stop processing if time has exceeded?

MongoDB v2.6.4, 64Bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes on [`MaxTimeMS` behaviour](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/#behaviors) as at MongoDB 2.6:

- `MaxTimeMS` sets a cumulative time limit in **milliseconds** for *processing operations* on a cursor.
- Network latency and idle time for a cursor do not count toward MaxTimeMS.
- After the MaxTimeMS is reached, the operation will be killed at the next safe interrupt point (for example, when that operation yields). This means that an operation can exceed MaxTimeMS if it is not currently interruptible.

From your [profile output](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/#system.profile.lockStats) the query held a read lock for 334 **microseconds** and yielded once, so it would appear to be well below the `MaxTimeMS` threshold. Effectively, this isn't an inherently "slow query" to execute but it is likely being affected by other activity on your system.

A properly indexed query returning a single result is unlikely to be slow; the `MaxTimeMS` option is much more useful for a poorly indexed query or a long running query that returns many results.

For a forced example of a slow executing query to test `MaxTimeMS` you could use a JavaScript function, eg:

```
// Add some test documents in the collection
db.mycoll.insert([{sleepy:1}, {tired:1}, {zzz:1}, {xyzzy:1}])

// A query that sleeps for 1s on each document found 
db.mycoll.find({$where: "sleep(1000) || true"}).maxTimeMS(50)
```

I would suggest looking at the query performance in aggregate as there are should be other performance metrics that correlate. You should ideally track your MongoDB metrics over time using a monitoring system. For monitoring suggestions, see [Monitoring for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/) in the manual.

Asya's presentation on [Diagnostics & Debugging](http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/diagnostics-and-debugging) also provides a good overview of performance troubleshooting tools and how they were used to solve some specific performance scenarios.

Comment: checking the stats in aggregation proves that in general timeout works, but though, we have some delayed or locked queries, using the same index, but the system hanging worse. the index is half size of available RAM, dedicated hardware server and RAID10 disk. about 200 insert/update and about 1300 findOne (on single field index) per second. most of these requests are processed without any delay, average time for read is 30ms, but for unknown there are hanging queries, taking up to 500ms and delaying all the application and other queries. still suffering on that behaviour issue.

Comment: Are you using any tools to monitor your MongoDB deployment? Is this a standalone, replica set, or sharded cluster? Asya's presentation has some great tips that would help with log-based forensics (in particular using [mtools](http://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools), which was developed by a colleague of ours at MongoDB, Inc).

Comment: @ledy: If your deployment is monitored in MMS or you are willing to share a recent log file including the slow queries, I can review the extra details.